# Why does Neural Network give same accuracies for permuted labels?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, deep-learning, p-value

I have a datset of 37 data points and around 1300 features. There are 4 different classes and each class has around the same number of data points. I have trained a neural network and got an accuracy of 60% with two hidden layers which is not bad (chance level 25%).

The problem is now with the p-value. I'm calculating the p-value with a permutation test. I'm permuting the labels 1000 times and for each permutation I'm calculating the accuracy. The p-value I calculate as the percentage of permutation accuracies which aver over the original accuracy.

For all the permutations of labels I'm getting the same accuracy as with the original labels, i.e. the neural network does not seem to include the labels in the learning.

If I do it with SVM I'm getting for all permutations different accuracies (in the end like a gaussian distribution).

Why is this the case?

By the way, I'm using the DeepLearnToolbox for Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the 60% success rate on the training data or a validation dataset that you set aside?

If you're computing the success rate on only the training data then you would also expect a high accuracy even after permuting the labels. This is because your classifier will overfit the data (1300 features to 37 data points) and achieve good performance on training data.